# How to avoid race condition in signal handler

Tags: c, concurrency, signals, race-condition

I am working on a project involving signal-driven I/O which may end up using a signal handler created with sigaction(). My concern is that the handler might be called multiple times. In other words, it will be processing message A, when it gets interrupted by message B and start processing B, possibly causing a problem. I have seen some code on the web that uses sigprocmask to avoid this, but it appears wrong to me. For example:

```
void handle_signal(int sig_num)
{
    sigset_t mask_set;  /* used to set a signal masking set. */
    sigset_t old_set;   /* used to store the old mask set.   */

    /* re-set the signal handler again to catch_int, for next time */
    signal(SIGINT, catch_int);
    /* mask any further signals while we're inside the handler. */
    sigfillset(&mask_set);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask_set, &old_set);

    .... (content handling code here) ....

    /* restore the old signal mask */{{/COMMENT_FONT}*/
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &old_set, NULL);
}
```

This is obviously wrong because sigprocmask is not atomic with the signal. In other words, there is a window of time between when the signal handler is called and when sigprocmask is called, and the signal handler could be called a second or third time in that window, creating a race condition.

My options:

(1) Use a semaphore inside of the handler to queue any redundant calls of the handler.

(2) Write the handler to be re-entrant, so it is fine for it to be called multiple times concurrently.

(3) Some other solution?

If I go for option (2) above, can I consider a socket read queue to be thread safe? For example, let's say a socket handler gets called twice. Instance A starts reading from the socket, then it is interrupted, and Instance B starts finishes reading the packet. Will this cause A to just find the queue empty and finish up or will I be at risk for some kind of error?

Comment: Do you mean `sigaction ()` for setting up the signal handler? I couldn't find anything about a `sigact ()` after a quick search.

Comment: @Andrew yes, I fixed that typo

Comment: Use `sigaction` and not `signal`, you will be able to *protect* your handler from being interrupted by any other signal you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `sigaction` to setup the signal handler then the signal that caused the handler to be triggered will by default already be blocked inside the handler.

In your code then the blocking of all signals and then the restore of the old mask is about blocking all *other* signals, the original signal (that triggered the handler) will be blocked until you return from the handler (or you specifically unblock it).

With `sigaction` you can avoid doing this block and restore in the handler by setting the `sa_mask` field of the `struct sigaction`, which is the set of signals blocked in the handler.

Further, your use of `signal` to "re-set" the handler is a little confusing, you call your function `handle_signal` then you re-set to `catch_int` (assuming this handler is actually handling `SIGINT`...

The older `signal` API did used to reset the signal handler back to the default each time the handler was triggered.  However, by default `sigaction` does not do this, so you shouldn't need to "re-set" the signal handler if you're using the `sigaction` API.  I personally would avoid mixing calls to `signal` and `sigaction` in the same program, I'd choose one and stick to it.

In conclusion, I think your concerns about `sigprocmask` not being atomic are unnecessary as the signal in question is already blocked, your mixed use of `signal` and `sigaction` worries me more.

Comment: It's not my code, its an example of what seemed wrong to me.

Comment: OK.  Hopefully the answer explains that your concerns are unnecessary.  I would recommend `sigaction` if that API is available to you, and read the `sigaction` manual which will provide much more detail.

Comment: If `sigprocmask()` etc can be used, `sigaction()` can be too — while I could imagine an implementation with `sigaction()` and no `sigprocmask()` (an implementation from the earlier part of the 1990s, perhaps), it is much, much less likely you'd find `sigprocmask()` without `sigaction()`; so much less likely that I'd consider it 'impossible' and not worry about the possibility.